# Which package extension file upload in magentocommerce?

Tags: extensions, package

I have created package extension in magento 1.9. So following three file created.

1. [My_Extension_Name].xml
2. [My_Extension_Name]-1.0.0.tgz
3. package.xml

When I login in my account on magento.com which file I have to upload,only need [My_Extension_Name]-1.0.0.tgz file upload ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope while packaging extension you have included all of your code related to your extension in the package. You might have packaged following files/folders

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml
app/code/<codePool>/Namespace/Module/etc/*
app/code/<codePool>/Namespace/Module/controllers/*
app/code/<codePool>/Namespace/Module/Block/*
app/code/<codePool>/Namespace/Module/Model/*
app/code/<codePool>/Namespace/Module/Helper/*
```

May be you have also packaged `layout` and `template` files present in your theme. 
You need to upload only your package `[My_Extension_Name]-1.0.0.tgz` to Magento connect https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect

Comment: I all included in my Package archive file and also checked after created package archive file and thanks for answer

Comment: Hi, is your extesnion is live as i facing issues while testing the extesnion on my local machine before submitting

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217669/how-to-use-create-extension-package-in-magento-1-9?noredirect=1&lq=1